# WebView gets under ActionBar

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

I am trying to have a transparent `ActionBar` that remains on top, but that covers the content of my view when I scroll down. I did it with a `ScrollView` surrounding the `WebView` but now I had to delete it because of other problems.

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context="com.example.app365.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.app365.MyWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/social1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: result]

I would like the webview content to get under the actionbar only after the first scroll...

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin top to your webview of `?actionBarSize`?

Comment: Yes but the webview ends up under the ActionBar and the transparency is useless. I want this effect, but at the beginning the webview content should be under the ActionBar